# grep: invalid UTF-8 byte sequence in input - error on piping grep to output of md5deep

Tags: linux, bash, grep

The md5deep utility allows to run command like this - 
    md5deep -r -l -j0 app

and gives output like this (recursive list of md5 hash of all the underlying files/directories, considering their content) -

```
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/cases/controllers/empty
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/cases/models/empty
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/cases/components/empty
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/cases/helpers/empty
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/cases/behaviors/empty
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/groups/empty
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  app/tests/fixtures/empty
```

Now, I am trying to restrict the output to only some matching files/directories, but the following commands -

```
md5deep -r -l -j0 app | grep -Po '.*app\/tests\/fixtures\/empty.*'
md5deep -r -l -j0 app | grep -Po '.*d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e*'
```

give me the following error -

```
grep: invalid UTF-8 byte sequence
```

*Note -* *I know that [md5deep](http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/md5deep.html) allows specifying a list of files, but I would like to make it work using regex, via grep, because what I actually want to do, is to specify a list of files which I want to ignore (config files of the application which may be setup specific).*

Comment: Perhaps see also https://bugs.debian.org/730472

Comment: Used the solution given in the linked answer like this -  `md5deep -r -l -j0 app | LC_ALL=C grep -Po '.*app\/tests\/fixtures\/empty.*'`